# SQL View with relational table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, linq-to-entities

I'm looking to create a view page for 2 tables which are:

```
tbArticle:
    articleid
    name 

tbArticleMedia:
    articleid
    mediaid
```

I'm looking to create the viewTable like this:

```
viewArticleMedia:
    ArticleId         (EG vale: 1)
    ArticleName       (EG vale: this is article)
    MultimediaId      (EG vale: 1,2,3,4,5)
```

Anyone please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
     a.articleId, a.Name,
     STUFF(
         (SELECT ',' + CAST(mediaid as VARCHAR(10))
          FROM  tbArticleMedia
          WHERE articleid = a.articleid
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS MultimediaId
FROM tbArticle AS a
     INNER JOIN tbArticleMedia b
        ON a.articleid = b.articleid
GROUP BY a.articleId, a.Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c2cf/8)